# How often should I lube with Pedros Ice Wax?

Tags: road-bike, chain, derailleur, lubricant

I'm a usa cycling road racer. I just got a recommended lube Pedros Ice Wax. I ride about 100 miles a week. How often should I lube my chain with it and how often should I clean it?

Comment: Never use the stuff, just a medium (neither wet nor dry) chain oil.

Comment: How often to lube depends mainly on environmental conditions and mileage. A low-mileage person living in an arid climate can probably go months between lubes, while a high-mileage rider in a wet climate probably needs to do it every few weeks.